# Find First Letter in a String

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a formula to find and return the first letter in a string.  So if a cell contains:

```
1234(*&^%$23ADFG54
```

the formula would return:

```
A
```

**EDIT#1:**

I am currently using the following *UDF:*

```
Public Function FirstLetter(Sin As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, CH As String
    FirstLetter = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(Sin)
        If Mid(Sin, i, 1) Like "[A-Z]" Then
            FirstLetter = Mid(Sin, i, 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

But I need a non-VBA solution.

Comment: SuperUser is not a "Please write me a script" site. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @LPChip Sorry........see my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably not the most elegant but it stays away from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`=MIN(INDEX(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+((CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<65)+(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>90))*1E+99,,))`

Just <kbd>Enter</kbd> normally. Fill down as necessary. Note that the `UPPER` makes it case-insensitive.

**How It Works**

1. An **A** is ASCII character 65 and a **Z** is 90. These numbers can be derived from a single string character using the [CODE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CODE-function-daabc849-79e2-4661-8145-0b33c8397d4b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).
2. You need to crawl through the string to be examined character by character. The [MID function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-MIDB-functions-61cf6b06-bdf0-4ff8-9319-60e31f3f5884?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) can peel out a single character from within the string but it needs a starting point which will increase by 1 until each character in the string has been examined.
3. Typically this is done with the [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROW-function-7f5b93c1-0cfa-4e83-8d81-a072213b9ab6?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) like `ROW(1:50)` to increment through numbers 1 to 50 if we knew that the string was 50 characters long. There is no guarantee of that string length so we have to construct the row reference using 1 and the [LEN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEN-LENB-functions-6a149d3a-ba2e-4394-ad47-2eb083265a56?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) then turn that concatenated string into a usable worksheet cell range address with the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).
4. The [UPPER function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/UPPER-function-3f91b8ab-86fd-45c4-94c1-586a2201ca09?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) was used on the string so that we only have to look for upper case ASCII character codes. If it wasn't in place the criteria would have to be doubled up to also compare to ASCII codes 97 (e.g. *a*) and 122 (e.g. *z*).
5. The [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-b61bc266-fe02-4852-aad9-77bf8ca3c036?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) is used in its *array form* to provide the iteration to crawl through the string character by character. Any character peeled out that is not within A-Z causes the number returned by `ROW(1:<length-of-string>)` at that position to be multiplied by 1E+99 (a very large number and not the minimum of anything on the worksheet). If it *is* within A-Z, the position or `ROW(1:<length-of-string>)` remains the same value.
6. So `INDEX` is returning an array of numbers (aka *positions*), some of which are in the 1E+99 range. The [MIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MIN-function-58c5be73-9206-4d5a-965a-eb9f419ee535?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) takes the smallest of these which represents the first alphabetic character in the string.
7. With that formula in the first cell, [fill down](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) as necessary to evaluate all the strings in column A. Easy-peasy.

It may be worthwhile to point out that using `ROW` like this to provide an incremental series of number for array processing is usually down by locking down the actual numbers as absolutes like `ROW($1:$50)` so they do not change when filled down. This is unnecessary here as the *"1:"* is text and will not change when the copied/filled to another location.

Comment: Can you add a couple of sentences to your answer to describe the gist of how the formula works?

Comment: **Thanks!**   It gives the *position,* but that's good enough!

Comment: Amazing and fast Excel-fu. +1

Answer (score 3):

Another way to determine the position

```
Column B

=MIN(FIND({"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"},UPPER(A1)&"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))
```

This returns the position of the first letter found. Returns Len(A1) + 1 in case no letter is found.

The first argument of Find is an array of all letters to find in the string. The second argument is the actual string in upper case along with all letters at the end so that the find function always returns a value for all the letters.

```
Column C

=IF(LEN(A1) >= B1, RIGHT(LEFT(A1, B1),1), "")
```

This returns the letter found in the string. In case the string has no letter, it would return empty.

Reference:
https://exceljet.net/formula/split-text-and-numbers

The link provides a solution for numbers. The above formula is switched for letters.